# FireDAC SQLITE : No such table column :PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO

Tags: delphi, firedac

i'm building app with delphi rio 10.3 with firedac sqlite3

pragma function not working with 'SELECT COMMAND' AS I Try Below:

```
procedure Tamdf.Button31Click(Sender:TObject);
begin
   MyFDQuery.Open('SELECT name FROM PRAGMA_table_info("DOCM")');
   ShowMessage(MyFDQuery.Fields[0].AsString);
end;
```

i receive ERROR message :"ERROR: no such table column: PRAGMA_table_info.name" 
what i did wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried doing 'SELECT * from ...' and seeing what the returned column names actually are?

Comment: The column name is true his name is "name" put no rsult return just error message
i tried the same line in 'DB BROWSER FOR SQLITE' program and it work fine without error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With FireDAC you can use workaround with create temp table "table_info":

```
MyFDQuery.Open(
  'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_info;' +
  'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table_info AS SELECT * FROM pragma_table_info("DOCM");' + 
  'SELECT name FROM table_info');
```

**Edit**

My environment: Delphi **10.3.2 Rio**, Win32, default SQLite 3.28.0 statically linked. No special settings.

Connection - `TFDConnection` with only:

```
FDConnection1.Params.DriverID := 'SQLite';
FDConnection1.Params.Database := 'D:\TMP\TEST.db';
```

Comment: For me, that returns the same error as quoted in my answer.  I wonder if it's a Sqlite version-specific problem?

Comment: @MartynA - it works fine, no errors. Delphi 10.3 Rio, SQLite 3.28.0 (default statically linked). It works fine also in other sqlite browsers (SQLiteSpy, ...).

Comment: Well, I'm using Seattle, just downloaded v.3.30.1 and still get the same result - works fine in FF Sqlite manager, same error I quoted in FireDAC.  Curious ...

Comment: @Branko
Tank's for answer but it's return the same error in firedac

Comment: @MartynA - I TRY SQLITE V 3.28 AND TRY V 3.30 IT'S THE SAME ERROR
the problem with FIREDAC

Comment: @AhmadMoneeb:  Presumably your system and mine have something in common which differs from Branko's.

Comment: @MartynA - No special settings. Please see my edit answer.

Comment: @AhmadMoneeb - as I can see from your question you have the same environment as I. I'm surprised it doesn't work.

Comment: @Branko Thank you, i tried your code again and it'work without error i will accept it answer 
even it give my solution for my code but not my problem with SQLITE3 FUNCTION IN FIREDAC

Answer (score 2):

The following code works fine for me on a Sqlite database containing the table `MyTable'.  I'm not sure the SQL you are using is correct for use in FireDAC

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FDQuery1.Active then
    FDQuery1.Close;
  FDQuery1.Open('PRAGMA Table_Info(''MyTable'')');
end;
```

It returns

```
 cid    name
 0       ID
 1       NAME
```

If nothing else, you could use FireDAC's LocalSQL to extract the `Name` from the returned result set.

I'll see if I can get SELECT working with the PRAGMA query ...

This query works fine in FireFox's Sqlite Manager add-in

```
select * from PRAGMA_table_info('mytable')
```

but returns the error

> no such table: PRAGMA_Table_Info'.

when executed by FDQuery1.

Comment: FDQuery1.Open('PRAGMA Table_Info(''MyTable'')');
THAT WOK FINE IN FIREDAC 
BUT  
    FDQuery.Open('SELECT name FROM PRAGMA_table_info("DOCM")');
GETTING ERROR

Comment: The SQLite's column metadata description function `sqlite3_table_column_metadata` fails for such SQL command. The problem is that there is no such table `pragma_table_info`, hence there is no such column to describe and SQLite returns failure (which then FireDAC propagates). But this table name is described by SQLite when calling `sqlite3_column_table_name` for the prepared statement, so I'd call this a problem of SQLite (they say, this is Bob and when we try to know more about Bob, they say they don't know anybody of this name).

Comment: i figure out where the problem , the problem with  FIREDAC it's not accept SQLITE3 Functions with SELECT statement directly ,with trying my code above it return error but @branko 's code work fine without error, i try my code in  DB BROWSER program :it work fine and directly

Comment: FireDAC might have a fallback for commands querying resultset returned by a function call (commands such as `SELECT TheColumn FROM TheFunction()`). SQLite now describes to FireDAC for such statement table name as `TheFunction` and FireDAC later asks SQLite for metadata for such table (which doesn't exist as it's a function, not table). There might be a fallback like if getting DB column metadata fails, FireDAC asks for statement column metadata.

Comment: @TLama:  Thanks, that sounds plausible, I'd noticed that FD does a much better job that may other libraries when it comes to retrieving and using metadata.  If this were SqlServer, I'd just fire up SSMS's profiler and have a look at what's actually being sent to the server, but tbh I'm not really familiar enough with FD and Sqlite to know how to do similar.  When I have a hour to spare, I'll try looking it up.